# Angular Set-Cookie does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-headers

In my Angular 5 application we use the http client to do post and get request. After login the back-end gives a command to set the Cookie which can be used to authenticate in the next requests.

This looks like:

```
Set-Cookie: portal_ci_session=XuATFg7Y7gwG3SKff83; path=/; secure; httponly
```

I have created a library to make a post request:

```
const myheader = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
const baseUrl = 'https://***/index.php/rest/';

@Injectable()
export class HttpprocessingService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private router: Router) { }

  // do an post request 
  public doPost(url : string,postparameters : any){

    var postbody = new HttpParams();        

    for(var key in postparameters) {
      postbody = postbody.append(key,postparameters[key]);
    }

    return this.http.post(baseUrl+url,postbody,{headers:myheader,withCredentials:true});
```

When i do a post request to the login in Chrome the Cookie is received trough the response header and automatically set in the request header of the next request.

But when using Safari this mechanism does not work. The response header with the Set-Cookie is the same but at the next request the request header is empty.

What did i do wrong?

I am running Angular in my localhost:4200.

Comment: Do you have microsoft edge? I'm experiencing what you are experiencing right now with Microsoft Edge and Safari with IOS 9.0 and below. It is so weird because it works fine with Mozilla, Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer version 8+. Can you post your solution if you ever find one?